# How to loop through dataframes in dictionary? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I stored multiple DataFrames in a dictionary,

```
df_dict = {product: product_df.drop(['productID', 'productName'],axis = 1).sort(['date'])
          for product, product_df in products}
```

The dictionary looks like this,

```
Key   Type      Size           Values
1   DataFrame  (100,2)  Column names: date, sales
2   DataFrame  (130,2)  Column names: date, sales
3   DataFrame  (115,2)  Column names: date, sales
4   DataFrame  (137,2)  Column names: date, sales
```

I would like to write a for loop to store each DataFrame forecasting results in a list or a dictionary. This is how I did it, the value in the dictionary is `DataFrames` and the key is `productID`

```
a = []
for key, value in df_dict:
    m = Prophet()
    m.fit(value)
    future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods = 365)
    forecast = m.predict(future)
    a.append(forecast)
```

However, in the list `a = []`, the index is reset rather than the keys in a dictionary. Is there any ways to store the results with keys as reference index?

Comment: Please look at (and post) the complete stack trace. It will tell you which lines of your programs are responsible for the error.

Comment: Iterating directly over a dictionary iterates over its *keys*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the information. It took time to iterate over a dictionary with 100+ DataFrames. Will try other ways to see if the run time improves.

Comment: The time it takes to actually loop over the 100 keys in a dictionary is trivial. If you must optimize, you should probably check whatever is going in inside your loop body. I dig the name `Prophet` by the way.